# Optimizing the nested for loop

Tags: c, linux, optimization

```
for (n = 0; n < L_SUBFR; n++)
{
    s = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        s += exc[i] * h1[n - i];
    }
    y1[n] = s;
}
```

Optimzed version:

```
for (n = L_SUBFR; n != 0; n--)
{
    for (i = n; i != 0; i--)
    {
        y1[n] = y1[n] + exc[i] * h1[n - i];
    }
}
```

I have run both the codes on `AMD opteron 6274` bit machine after compilation with `gcc 4.4.6.` however, I am not able to see any gain in speed or execution time.

(1) Is there any way I can optimize the above code further?

(2) Can any one tell me why i am not able to see the gain ?

Comment: Why would the second version be faster? Besides, they aren't of equivalent functionality

Comment: **Leave such optimizations to the compiler** (assuming both versions are doing the same, which is doubtful). The compiler is much better for this than you and me together.

Comment: Any cycle you might save in the inner loop is completely swamped by the cycles spent in the `y1` assignment statement. Then the cycle you might save in the outer loop is *totally* swamped by the inner loop.

Comment: Seems that you are doing lots of MAC operations. AMD opteron have SIMD instructions for that. See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set)

Comment: It seems optimize to me as I am removing an intermediate variable in between, which is s. Can any tell me how many + or - or * or / operations can be used in single instruction for AMD  opetron 6274. For example, d= a*b+ p*q + r*s + u/v. How many cycles should this take or in other ways can the above instruction be executed in 1 single cycle?

Answer (score 2):

You should focus on making readable code rather than "fast" code. Speed is gained by making your algorithms more efficient:

*You gain more performance by replacing naive sorts with quick sort, not by replacing `(i != 0)` with `(i)`.*

The compiler does all of that for you anyway.

---

I'll recap quoting the updated questions listed:

> (1) Is there any way I can optimize the above code further?

Sure, you can replace `(i != 0)` and `(n != 0)` with `(i)` and `(n)` and do all kinds of shenanigans and nitpicking with the code to make it just a bit faster, but in the end, you wouldn't really be changing anything because your compiler does even more optimizations. Often, it can optimize the assembly generated directly.

> (2) Can any one tell me why i am not able to see the gain?

The compiler my friend. Even if the compiler didn't do anything here, you're not going to notice a gain unless you have nano-second precision timers. Ultimately, it depends on your definition of `L_SUBFR`.

---

Just for kicks, here's an example of what the compiler can do:

```
unsigned int i = getValue();

if (i >= 10 && i <= 200) {

}
```

That code that seems so minimal, so irreducible, can be optimized by the compiler to this:

```
unsigned int i = getValue();

if (i - 10 <= 190) {

}
```

Comment: Just nitpicking: the compiler don't optimize the assembler, it optimizes some internal representations (e.g. *Gimple* for GCC whose version 4.8 has just been released).... and the transformed internal representations are later transformed to assembler (via some other representations, like RTL in GCC)

Comment: I guess that sounds more feasible, I mean, how much would you have to pay a programmer to make an optimizer for Assembly code directly? :D

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Plan 9 has one. In Plan 9, an object file is just some kind of "binary assembler". The linker does some kind of assembly optimization such as instruction selection.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Just nitpicking: assembler code can be optimized too (peephole optimization). LLVM makes quite a good job of it.

Comment: It is not assembly code, but an internal representation close to it, which is subject to peephole optimization (and GCC does peephole optimization at the RTL level too).